# connect Raspberry Pi3 with Xbee

Tags: pi-3

I used Xbee s1 pro (configured as EndDvice) connected to raspberry Pi3 for getting the RSSI of another Xbee s1 pro configured as coodinator. I've the following error in first line (from xbee import Xbee, ZigBee) of my python program: No module named xbee. Knowing that i added the package "digi-xbee" but i can't add "xbee" one.
Could you help me for fixing this error ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I wrote a program on python for getting RSSI of xbee module which is connected to raspberry pi3. The execution of this program shows this error: ImportError: no module named 'xbee'

Answer (score 1):

You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/tree/master/examples)

Here is an example of import in a script header file:

```
import digi.xbee.devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem after update and upgrade my python 2.7 to python3.8

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.